# Can I add a "Edit Filter" to the top of this sub menu?

Tags: menu, mfc

At this point in time this is just a standard `CMenu` on a `CDialog`:

[image: Language menu]

Is it possible to have some kind of filter item in the menu so that a user could type in part of the language string and it filter down the available languages?

Comment: A `CMenu` wraps the functionality of a Win32 [Menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/menus). Besides the ability to simulate radio buttons and check boxes, there's no built-in facility to provide interactivity. There's also no built-in customization point to host other controls. I've never used [CMFCPopupMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcpopupmenu-class), and don't know what functionality it has to offer. Maybe there's something in there you could use.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but common controls have usability-based limitations. Menus (or other list-kind controls) with more than a couple dozens entry are not user-friendly. I would make `Language` a command, and bring up some rich UI with proximity search functionality. N.B. I am having hard time finding US (or United States?) in those lists that may or may not be alphabetically sorted :)

Comment: @VladFeinstein I don’t offer US. Just English.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle - oh, I was just using it as an example of poorly designed UI.

Comment: The CMFCMenuBar class offers a feature showing the most recently menu command first (on top) and hides the rest (there's an arrow at the bottom that unfolds the menu). But I think you can't make it work for one menu item only (can be set for the whole menu-bar), and for short menus it's rather counterproductive, even frustrating.

Comment: I think it's quite obvious: You should rather use a combo box instead of a menu. A combo box offers the feature you're requesting. But of course you cannot open it inside the sub-menu and need to implement a popup dialog containing it.